# Show that $\frac{1}{n}<\ln n$, for all $n>1$ where n is a positive integer

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Show that $\frac{1}{n}<\ln n$, for all $n>1$ where n is a positive integer

I've tried using induction by multiplying both sides by $\ln k+1$ and $\frac{1}{k+1}$ but but all it does is makes it more complicated, I've tried using the fact that $k>1$ and $k+1>2$ during the inductive $k+1$ step, but I'm still stuck.

Looking for clues for this question.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing as $n$ increases but $\ln(n)$ is increasing in $n$

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm confused as to how to tackle the proof.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}<\ln(n)<\ln(n+1)$, where the middle inequality is your induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n \ge 2$ we have:

$1/n \le 1/2 < \ln 2 \le \ln n$.

Comment: $1/2<\ln 2$ is true because $1=\ln e<\ln 4=\ln 2^2=2\ln 2$ because $e<4$ and $\ln x$, $x>0$ is a strictly increasing function and by logarithm properties.

Comment: A little bir easier: $ \ln 2 =0,6931....$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\frac1{k}<\ln(k)$. Then: $$\frac1{k+1}<\frac1{k}<\ln(k)<\ln(k+1)$$

Now you just have to show $\frac12<\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

$e \lt n^n$ for $n\gt 1.$

Take $\log$ of both sides:

$1 \lt n\log(n)$  $   $ $\rightarrow:$

$1/n \lt \log(n)$ for $n \gt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the statement is true if $n=2$.  Now consider $f(x) = \ln x - \frac{1}{x}$.  Since $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x+1}{x^2}$ is clearly positive for $x \geq 2$, $f$ is increasing over the same span.  Thus the gap between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\ln n$ is only getting wider, so we have $\frac{1}{n} < \ln(n)$ for $n \geq 2$.